# Boolean nonlinear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, modular-arithmetic

**I received an assignment which I have problems to understand. The question is as follows:**

---

Consider the following Boolean function from $Z_2^4$ to $Z_2$:

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1 +x_2 +x_3 +x_4 +x_1x_2x_3x_4$.

***Prove that $f(x)$ is nonlinear.***

(Hint: Use the definition of nonlinear functions. Specifically, Find out two elements $x$ ∈ $Z_2^4$ and $y$ ∈ $Z_2^4$ such that $f(x + y)  \neq f(x) + f(y)$ .)

---

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(1,1,0,0) = 0, \; f(0,0,1,1) = 0, \, f(1,1,1,1) = 1$.

Comment: How did you reach your answer?

Comment: Got it, forgot it is boolean arithmetic. Altough, I think alle those three examples should be equal to 1.

Comment: @Jurge92 why? $f(1,1,0,0) = 1 + 1 +0+0+0 = 0$. Don't forget "+" is addition modulo 2.

Comment: Could you please provide your complete calculations? Wouldn't $1+1+0+0+0=1$? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I just realised $(1+1) mod 2 = 0$.